# how to get users id in django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get id from logged user to filter query in models.how to get users id in django model?
Thanks

in `models.py`:

```
class Portfo(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sell = models.ForeignKey(Sell, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    profit = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    final_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    def final_amount(self):
        final_amount = 0
        buy = Buy.objects.filter(product_id=self.product.id, owner__exact=...)
        sell = Sell.objects.filter(product_id=self.product.id)
```

Comment: Isn't that the user assigned to the `.customer`?

Comment: Why can `customer` be `null=True` by the way?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i want to filter buy objects by owner, not customer. owners are super admin.

Comment: well models are request-unaware, since one can also run for example management scripts that have no user. You will need to pass the logged in user through a parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem:  it's true,Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get id from logged user to filter query in models.

Models are designed to be request-unaware. If you want to retrieve the user id, you will need to pass it through a parameter, so:

```
class Portfo(models.Model):
    # …

    def final_amount(self, user_id):
        final_amount = 0
        buy = Buy.objects.filter(product_id=self.product_id, owner_id=user_id)
        sell = Sell.objects.filter(product_id=self.product_id, owner_id=user_id)
        # …
```

In the view, you can then use the `.final_amount(…)` method, for example with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def some_view(request, pk):
    my_porfolio = get_object_or_404(Portfolio, pk=pk)
    final_amount = my_portfolio.final_amount(request.user.id)
    # …
```